# foreign keys in activerecord migrations vs. schema.rb

Tags: ruby, activerecord, foreign-keys

I'm running activerecord 3.0.0beta. I know you can create columns with foreign keys like

```
create_table "my_things" do |t|
  t.reference "other_thing_id"
end
```

but I forgot and just made it a plain integer. Now, I've added a migration like

```
execute("alter table my_things add constraint fk_other_thing foreign key (other_thing_id) references other_things(id)")
```

That worked fine, but I don't see anything equivalent appear in schema.rb (I was hoping for `t.reference`), so if I did a schema load, I wouldn't get my constraint. What's the best way to fix that?

Comment: Actually, t.references doesn't work in plain rails anyway, which would explain my issue; in fact, it's a feature of foreigner. I must have been reading about that when I discovered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [foreigner](http://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner). It helps you create foreign keys in your migrations and also adds them to your schema.rb.

Comment: Cool. I'd seen it but didn't know if it support schema.rb. I'll check it out.